# terraform helm release cannot re-use a name that is still in use

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy an helm chart to a k8s cluster using terraform, it runs fine the first time, but when I try to update the chart I found myself with this error:

[image]

`Error: cannot re-use a name that is still in use │  │   with helm_release.deliverable, │   on main.tf line 8, in resource "helm_release" "deliverable": │    8: resource "helm_release" "deliverable" {`

Now, if I delete the chart it will work fine ( the first run ), but I don't want to do that everytime, is there a way to reutilise the releasename?

here is my code:

```
resource "helm_release" "deliverable" {
  name                = "releaseapp"
  namespace           = "appnamespace"
  repository          = "https://myrepo/repository/helm/"
  chart               = "releaseapp"
  version             = "0.2.0"
  repository_username = "myuser"
  force_update        = true
  wait                = true
  repository_password = var.acrpass


  set {
    name  = "namespace"
    value = "appnamespace"
  }

  set {
    name  = "image.tag"
    value = var.applicationversion
  }

  set {
    name  = "image.tag"
    value = var.applicationversion
  }

  set {
    name  = "timestamp"
    value = local.timestamp_sanitized
  }
}

locals {
  timestamp                    = "${timestamp()}"
  timestamp_sanitized          = "${replace("${local.timestamp}", "/[- TZ:]/", "")}"
}
```

I tried to change the helm chart version
I tried to add both

```
  force_update        = true
  wait                = true
```

but still no success. Would you be able to help me, please?

Comment: How are you updating? Your screenshot shows it adding a new helm release rather than modifying an existing one.

Comment: I create a new tag and I push it to the repo, that will trigger the deployment, terraform will init the remote state, then the chart version will be updated with the tag.

Comment: The behavior indicates that it is not reading/writing a remote state and is instead starting from a blank state.

Comment: @jordanm You were right, that was a tf state related problem. Do you want to move your comment into an answer, so that i can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitlab CI infrastructure terraform state wont accept special characters in its name, so no state were created. Therefore when trying to read from it, it failed and tries to create a new resource that already existed.

I had my state name create from the git branch that in the first case was feature/jira-task

changing from:

```
${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/terraform/state/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
```

TO:

```
${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/terraform/state/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}_tfstate
```

Solved the problem.